# "The kernel was blocked for an uncommon reason" - what are these reasons?

Tags: cuda, profiling, gpgpu, nvvp

The nvvp CUDA profiler frontend offers an analysis breaking down the causes for warps waiting for execution of their next instruction. We have categories such as "Execution latency", "Memory dependency", "Texture dependency", etc. - and one category named "Other":

[image]

The pie chart's legend says:

> Other - "The kernel was blocked for a[n] uncommon reason"

[image]

My questions:

- Does that mean the profiler can't figure out why execution was blocked, or is it just aggregating "uncommon reasons"?
- What are the more "common uncommon" reasons? As you can see, in some cases they can be far from negligible.
- Is there a list of all "uncommon reasons" somewhere?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887807/what-are-other-issue-stall-reasons-displayed-by-the-nsight-profiler) may be of interest.  I also believe Greg Smith has answered similar questions on various forums, you may be able to find other examples

Comment: "Other forums" = nvidia devtalk; someplace else?

Comment: I didn't say other forums, I said various forums.  I have not done an exhaustive search, but the 2 that came to mind were here on the SO `cuda` tag and nvidia devtalk, yes.