# What does NSight Compute show for a stall reason that isn't "supported"?

Tags: cuda, profiling, nsight-compute

The [CUDA Profiling Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ProfilingGuide/index.html) lists various [reasons](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ProfilingGuide/index.html#statistical-sampler) for sampled warp stalls, e.g. Allocation, Barrier, LG Throttle etc. And - the NSight Compute profiler shows the distribution of these as part of the profiling results.

The thing is, some of the stall reasons are listed as only being supported starting from some Compute Capability, e.g. "LG Throttle: 7.0+"

My question: What happens in devices of earlier compute capability, when the stall reason is this "unsupported" reason? Or, in other words, what is the fall-back for each of the listed stall reasons?

In Ye Olde NVIDIA Visual Profiler, we had an "Other" stall reason, see:

[What are "Other" Issue Stall Reasons displayed by the Nsight profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887807/what-are-other-issue-stall-reasons-displayed-by-the-nsight-profiler)

but I don't see this in (my version of) NSight Compute.

Answer (score 3):

Nsight Compute is [not supported and not the recommended profiler for GPUs with a compute capability prior to 7.0](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ReleaseNotes/index.html#gpu-support).

There is no formal definition for the behavior of the tool in an unsupported setting.  Consider it UB.

Use a legacy profiler (nvvp, nvprof) for a GPU with compute capability prior to cc7.0.

Comment: Nsight Compute 2019.5 can be used for Pascal GPUs with the exception of GP100.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor: Wait, so if that's true, then what _does_ Nsight Compute show for pre-7.0 GPUs and 7.0 stall reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Profiling a kernel with Nsight Compute 2019.5 on a Pascal GPU (sm_61), the metrics `LG Throttle` and `Sleeping` which require 7.0+ do not show up as stall reasons.

[image: Warp states Pascal]

Comment: I wonder if they show up as "Stall Wait" instead...